# Decryption and using the Like SQL Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption

I am relatively new to SQL and PostgreSQL and was wondering, if there is a way to use the like key word and pgp_sym_decrypt without decrypting the entire column to use the like statement (i.e)

```
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt("Column_Name", 'Password_Number') FROM Table_Name 
WHERE pgp_sym_decrypt("Column_Name", 'Password_Number') LIKE '%a%';
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and this will cause a linear search of the entire table when it's used. The decrypted value to be evaluated for like will have to be done for every record in the table.